# Where is Seminaire Bourbaki on-line?

Tags: online-resources, bourbaki

Where is Seminaire Bourbaki on-line?

The reason I ask is that for years it was complicated-enough already to find it in traditional libraries, as it would be catalogued according to its venue or ephemeral names of various aspects of it.

With the advent of the internet, because most of the Sem. Bourb. archive was so old, there was no obvious, easy way to convert it to digital, and, obviously, scanning-in cannot be done overnight.

EDIT: and, to make clear(er) what has been so obvious to me for decades that I'd failed to explain it in the question... for many decades, Sem. Bourb. consisted of not-too-long superb expositions by superb mathematicians of other superb mathematicians' important work. (Although at some point many of these transcripts were in English, not French), as I say to my students, the existence of decades of Sem. Bourb. transcripts is reason enough to learn how to read mathematical French.

Comment: Until 2006 it is on [numdam](http://numdam.org/numdam-bin/feuilleter?j=SB&sl=0)

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, as in my pseudo-answer, apparently it is still at numdam, at least as far as I can tell.

Comment: I meant issues that are available there - tome 1-48, 1948-2006

Comment: Ah, ok, I understand now: I'll edit my "answer"...

Comment: It's published by the SMF in their Asterisque series, and for reasons unknown to me the SMF resists putting their books online (even with a subscription scheme) in the 21st century. Sad!

Comment: For the recent ones, go to [http://www.bourbaki.ens.fr](http://www.bourbaki.ens.fr) and follow the links.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger: you can get electronic copies of Bourbaki seminars with a subscription, see http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/Asterisque/2016/380/html/smf_ast_380.php and the most recent texts seem available free of charge: http://www.bourbaki.ens.fr/seminaires/2016/Prog_nov16.html

Answer (score 10):

This is an extension on Paul's answer, but it would have been too extensive of an edit so I posted this separately.

(I have corrected the link in Paul's post since the old one was no longer working)

> Articles from **1948** (creation) up to **2006** can be found at [this](http://www.numdam.org/actas/SB/) link in Paul's post
>
> Articles *after* 2006 can also be purchased from SMF (Société Mathématique de France) at the following links: [2006-2007](http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/Asterisque/2008/317/html), [2007-2008](http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/Asterisque/2009/326/html), [2008-2009](http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/Asterisque/2010/332/html), [2009-2010](http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/Asterisque/2011/339/html), [2010-2011](http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/Asterisque/2012/348/html), [2011-2012](http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/Asterisque/2013/352/html), [2012-2013](http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/Asterisque/2014/361/html), [2013-2014](http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/Asterisque/2015/367-368/html), [2014-2015](http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/Asterisque/2016/380/html), [2015-2016](http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/Asterisque/2017/390/html), [2016-2017](http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/Asterisque/2017/390/html), (articles after 2017 can only be accessed, at the time of posting this, by clicking "PDF" next to the bolded article title at the following links: [2018](http://www.bourbaki.ens.fr/seminaires/2018/), [2019](http://www.bourbaki.ens.fr/seminaires/2019/)).

<s>Note: Since the 2019 seminar is 3 days from the time of writing this, those files are not available at this time.</s>

As of April 1st, the articles from the March 2019 seminar are available at the link above.

> If you are wanting to download an article published **after 2006**, you just need to know the corresponding Exposé number which can be found under "CONTENU DU VOLUME" on the SMF links above, after which the article can be found at links with this format:
>   `http://www.bourbaki.ens.fr/TEXTES/(put the exposé # here).pdf`. 
> For example, http://www.bourbaki.ens.fr/TEXTES/1108.pdf

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to @nfdc's comment following up on a comment of mine to the question [Compactness of the automorphic quotient](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/260407/compactness-of-the-automorphic-quotient/260426), I/we should know that Sem. Bourb. is archived in the numdam.org at

http://www.numdam.org/actas/SB/

EDIT: As @მამუკაჯიბლაძე observes in a comment, this includes the seminar up through 2006.

Comment: Yes, I know it's partly silly to ask and answer a question, but I thought this particular data-point would be useful to this site.

Comment: The "asterisque" series, which publishes among other things the Bourbaki seminar, is regularly updated on Numdam... with a 10 years moving wall (hence year 2007 should appear there in the next year). As far as I understand, this decision of the SMF is to protect their revenue stream from selling the paper copies.

Answer (score 5):

Here you have a complete and updated set of resources
https://www.bourbaki.fr/index-en.html

- Elements of mathematics 
  and, in particular, the two new volumes (Topologie Algébrique and Théories Spectrales)

  Séminaire Betty B. 
  The junior Bourbaki Seminar

  N. Bourbaki Seminar 
  The very one 
  Previous sessions

  Recorded talks of the séminaire N. Bourbaki
  (on youtube)

  Earlier Texts 
  Volumes of the Seminar since its creation. 
  Texts of the Bourbaki Seminar lectures until 2010  (on Numdam)

  Poincaré Seminar 
  If you like Physics.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in the actual talks, rather than the books, you can find it on youtube, [here](https://www.youtube.com/user/PoincareInstitute/videos). They also stream them in direct, during the talks !